# How to reduce higher order linear ODE to a system of first order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any general and systematic way of reducing the higher order linear ODE to a system of first order ODE?

For example, assume we have $a_3x^{(3)}+a_2x^{(2)}+a_1x^{(1)}+a_0x=0$, then how do we convert this into matrix form(a system of first order ODE). And after we solve the system of equation, how to combine them into our final solution $x(t)$?

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Do you know that this particular kind of DE has a very easy to find solution which doesn't require such tricks?

Comment: I know, plugin formula is just an easy thing. But I would like to know how to get those solutions, the process. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with
$$
x^{(n)}=f(t,x,x',x'',\ldots,x^{(n-1)}),
$$
you get the system
\begin{align*}
x_1&=x\\
x_1'&=x'=x_2\\
x_2'&=x''=x_3\\
&\ldots\\
x_{n-1}'&=x^{(n-1)}=x_{n}\\
x_n^{'}&=x^{(n)}=f(t,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n)
\end{align*}

Comment: And one last question, after we get the solution vector, is the solution we need the first entry of that vector?($x_1$) And the matrix is pretty sparse. When we deal with this matrix, is there any trick to diagonalize it(or Jordan normal form)?

Comment: Yes, your solution is just $x_1$. I do not quite understand why you need to diagonalize it. However, if the system is linear, the matrix form will show you where the characteristic equation appears from (this will be exactly $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$).

Comment: In my class notes, I didn't copy it clearly, but it says the fundamental solution is $\{t^{r_i}e^{\lambda_i t}$ for $r_i\in\{0,..,d_{i-1}\}\}$ but I am not sure what it means, because how do we locate the correct eigenvalue corresponding to $x_1$ (rather than $x_2$ or so)

Comment: It actually does not matter which $\lambda$ corresponds to which variable in the system. What you need to do is to 1) solve $\det (A-\lambda I)$ and find corresponding $\lambda$s with their corresponding algebraic multiplicities; 2) form the fundamental solution set as $\{e^{\lambda_i t}\}$ for those lambdas that have multiplicities one, $\{e^{\lambda_i t},te^{\lambda_i t}\}$ for lambdas that have multiplicities two and so on.

Comment: And one more thing: Lambdas do not correspond to $x_1,x_2,\ldots$. They correspond to _eigendirections_, which may be quite arbitrary.

Comment: But this is actually a confusing part for me. For example, if we have $x''-3x'+2x=0$ then each $\lambda$ has multiplicity one. but we know that the solution of this equation doesn't involve $te^{\lambda t}$

Comment: Because in this case actually matrix $A$ in the corresponding system is diagonalizable :) A better answer would be: We know that the dimension of the set of solutions is 2 and we already have linearly independent solutions $e^{\lambda_1t}$ and $e^{\lambda_2 t}$, hence no room for anything else.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I get it. So in the solution vector every entry is a solution to this system. In the end, we just need to solve the characteristic equation and linearly combine them.

Comment: Right. For the linear _equation_. For a general linear system (whose matrix does not have this special and sparse form) some additional subtleties arise. But not many )