# How to derive the higher order linear ODE from autonomous $1$st order ODE?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I know the following:

[How to reduce higher order linear ODE to a system of first order ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501745/how-to-reduce-higher-order-linear-ode-to-a-system-of-first-order-ode)

Now I want to consider the revsersed side:

Suppose I have the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{y_1}\\ \dot{y_2}\\ \dot{y_3}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow \dot{\hat{y}} = A\hat{y}$$

If $A$ is not a function of $t$, how to show the following ($i=1,2,3$):

$$\dddot{y}_i + b_2\ddot{y}_i+b_1\dot{y}_i+b_0y_i = 0$$

can be expressed as

$$\det\big(A-I(\frac{d}{dt})\big)y_i(t)=0$$

---

How to derive it? Can anyone give me the sketch of the derivation or a hint? 
Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that's smart, and so obvious that most people won't ask for a formal proof. But you seem to worry about those who do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply Cayley-Hamilton,
$$
\chi_A(\frac d{dt})y(t)=\chi_A(A)y(t)=0.
$$