# Need help in linearizing a non-linear system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems, linearization

We have the system
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = (1-x)^2-y^2\\
\dot{y} = \epsilon^{xy}-1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and I must plot the phase graph.

To do this I already know that I must linearize in the first order, since for Taylor degree $\geq2 \ $, $\Delta x \to 0$. However I am stuck and cannot even start.

I have in my mind that I must be able to set the system in such a way such that
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
y=\text{something}\\
\dot{y}= \text{other something}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
so that then I can run
\begin{align}
F(x+h)=F(x_0)+h\cdot \dfrac{dF}{dx}|_{x=x_0}.
\end{align}

The critical points of the starting system are $(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0)$.

Comment: Can you compute the Jacobian of your system?

Comment: Sure! It's 
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2(1-x) & -2y\\
x \epsilon^{xy} & y \epsilon^{xy}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
what does that say?

Comment: You can find the behavior near the critical points by computing the Jacobian evaluated at those points.

Comment: It is the linearisation of the system (the $F'$ term in your Taylor expansion). Now you need to evaluate it at $\vec{x} = \vec{x}_{0}$ where $\vec{x}_{0}$ are the critical points.

Comment: @MatthewCassell can you give me an article so I can read up on this? Or a worked example?

Comment: @MatthewCassell OH now I think I get it

Comment: @MatthewCassell so next step would be to calculate for example 
$F(x+h) = F(0,1) + h \dfrac{d F}{dx}|_{x=(0,1)}??$

Comment: We're being very loose with the notation but yes, that is essentially the point.

Comment: @MatthewCassell and what would be the form of $F(x+h)$? The whole Jacobian?

Comment: Forget the $F(x + h)$, it is just describing a perturbation to the system. Just note that the linear approximation of your system is given by the Jacobian of the RHS of your ODE system. Then evaluate the Jacobian matrix at the critical points of the system and determine the stability of those critical points from the form of the eigenvalues. Also, [these notes](http://alun.math.ncsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/01/linearization.pdf) go through the problem at a basic level and might clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: @MatthewCassell I know about the eigenvalues but in my notes from class I see that the teacher made a differential equation out of the system by setting it as described above $\dot{y} = \text{something}, y = \text{somethingelse}$ so that $y, \dot{y}$ had a known form and as such could be solved linearly.

Comment: I can't answer a question about what your teacher did without seeing the working. It sounds like you might be describing the reduction of a second order (or higher) ODE into a system of first order equations (though the fact that the resulting system you describe is of the form $(y, \dot{y})$ doesn't match with this unless there is a typo in your teachers work). Perhaps the information [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501745/how-to-reduce-higher-order-linear-ode-to-a-system-of-first-order-ode) will help you.

Comment: What is $ϵ^z$? You are using it like $\exp(z)$, not like $\exp(\ln(ϵ)\,z)$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann no no it's an epsilon to a power. $\epsilon^{xy}$

Comment: Then the second formula applies and you should get a factor $\ln(ϵ)$ in the partial derivatives. This will influence the type of equilibrium.

Comment: @LutzLehmann oh yeah that's a typo on my part. Will look into this and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have the system

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})$$

we can linearize this system in point $\mathbf{x}_0$ by using the Jacobian evaluatd at the point $\mathbf{x}_0$ the following method.

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\right]=J_F|_{\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0}\left[\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\right]$$

For your system this works as follows for your equilibrium point $\mathbf{x}_0=[x_0,y_0]^T$:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[x-x_0\right]= \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[(1-x^2) -y^2 \right]\right|_{x=x_0, y=y_0}\left[x-x_0\right] + \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[(1-x^2) -y^2 \right]\right|_{x=x_0, y=y_0}\left[y-y_0\right]$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[y-y_0\right]= \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\epsilon^{xy} -1\right]\right|_{x=x_0, y=y_0}\left[x-x_0\right] + \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[\epsilon^{xy} -1 \right]\right|_{x=x_0, y=y_0}\left[y-y_0\right]$$

In order to differentiate $\epsilon^{xy}$ you can rewrite it to  $\epsilon^{xy}=\exp\left[xy\ln\epsilon \right]$. Executing the partial derivatives and inserting $\mathbf{x}_0=[x_0,y_0]^T$ will lead to

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[x-x_0\right]= -2(1-x_0)\left[x-x_0\right] -2y_0\left[y-y_0\right]$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[y-y_0\right]= y_0\epsilon^{x_0y_0}\ln\epsilon^{}\left[x-x_0\right] +x_0\epsilon^{x_0y_0}\ln\epsilon\left[y-y_0\right]$$

We often replace $x-x_0=\Delta x$ and $y-y_0=\Delta y$. Hence, we can rewrite the equations as:

$$\Delta \dot{x}= -2(1-x_0)\Delta x -2y_0\Delta y$$
$$\Delta \dot{y}= y_0\epsilon^{x_0y_0}\ln\epsilon^{}\Delta x +x_0\epsilon^{x_0y_0}\ln\epsilon\Delta y$$

or in matrix form

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt}\Delta\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2(1-x_0) & -2y_0\\ 
y_0\epsilon^{x_0y_0}\ln\epsilon^{} & x_0\epsilon^{x_0y_0}\ln\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}\Delta\mathbf{x}.
$$

Comment: And how can we plot the phase graph from that?

Comment: You have to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix. Direction of the lines in the phase diagram is determined by the real part of the eigenvalue (negative direction towards equilibrium, positive outwards from equilibrium). If the eigenvalues have a complex part you will get spiral lines. If the eigenvalues are real only the eigenvectors dictate the direction of the lines. For examples see https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/phaseplane.aspx.