# How to reduce O.D.E. into first order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

How to reduce the following O.D.E. into first order?

> $v v_{yyy} + 2 v v_{yy}-v_{y}v_{yy} + v_{y} v^3 + v_y v -v_{y}^2 = 0$,
>
> where $v=v(y)$ and $v_{y}$ is the derivative w.r.t. $y$. I tried it by integration but I couldn't
> find the derivative for 2nd and 5th terms.

Comment: This may be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501745/how-to-reduce-higher-order-linear-ode-to-a-system-of-first-order-ode  

It is useful if you show us what you have tried. That way we can give a better response.

Comment: @WaterDrop, In my case equation is nonlinear ODE. The link you shared is about linear ODE.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is no different from reducing a linear $n$-th order ODE to a linear system of $1$st order ODEs: Write
$$
\mathbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}u_0\\u_1\\u_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v\\v_y\\v_{yy}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\dot{u}=\frac{d}{dy}u\,.$ Then your ODE becomes the system
\begin{align}
\dot{u}_0&=u_1\,,\\
\dot{u}_1&=u_2\,,\\
0&=u_0\,\dot{u}_2+2\,u_0\,u_2-u_1\,u_2+u_1\,u_0^3+u_1\,u_0-u_1^2\,.
\end{align}

Comment: @ Kurt G., Then we have O.D.E for vector $\textbf{u}$? How about if we require for a scalar function? I tried dividing $v^2$ and then we have $(\frac{v_{yy}}{v})' + \frac{1}{2}(v^2)' + 2 \frac{v_{yy}}{v} + (\ln v)' - ((\ln v )')^{2}=0$, where $'$ means the derivative w.r.t. $y$. How to proceed further?

Comment: Solving the $u$-system is as difficult as solving the original non-linear equation. Apparently you are asking a different question about which I have absolutely no idea. Is that homework? Context?

Comment: No, it is not homework.